# Import wizard wont allow me to insert columns and rows from CSV that has (4 Columns ) into a table has 5 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

Import wizard wont allow me to  insert 1200 rows from CSV that has (4 Columns ) into a table has 5 columns and the extra column on the table is( ID Primary key)
i can do it in brand new table but doesn't suit my requirement.
i tried :
INSERT INTO Table_name
     (Date , Park, Labor, Min,Floor)
  SELECT  date , Park ,labor, Min, Floor  FROM Table_name

and it doesn't work either.

Im Lost here!

Answer (score 0):

If the PK is an identity column (look it up), and IDENTIY_INSERT is off (which it is by default) then you'll be able to insert the rows you want.

Comment: i think the problem is the primary key or the ID column!

Comment: Yep, it certainly is.

Comment: well i didnt quite understand what shall i do!

Comment: yes but i need PK on the table as a requirement,can you tell me what the statment should be?

Comment: of course you need a pk. if it is an identity column, you can insert all other values but not the PK, and it automatically populates the column. As you would have read about, had you looked this up as suggested.

Comment: the problem is  i cant import the data to table has PK ,here is no other way?